# Фильтрация блоков при выборе option в двух select

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой js код:

```
$('.change-classes').on('change', function () {
    selectVal = $('.change-classes option:selected').text();
    obj = $('.lessons-list .lessons-block');
    for (i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj.eq(i).attr('data-class') != selectVal) {
                obj.eq(i).css({
                display: 'none'
            });
        }
        else {
            obj.eq(i).css({
                display: 'inherit'
            })
        }
    }
})

$('.change-objects').on('change', function () {
    selectVal = $('.change-objects option:selected').text();
    obj = $('.lessons-list .lessons-block');
    for (i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj.eq(i).attr('data-object') != selectVal) {
            obj.eq(i).css({
                display: 'none'
            });
        }
        else {
            obj.eq(i).css({
                display: 'inherit'
            })
        }
    }
})
```

По сути он задумывался как то, что поможет фильтровать показ блоков при определённом выборе, но работает не так, т.к. если делать выбор лишь в одном `select`, то всё нормально, но если подключить второй `select`, то уже всё идет не правильно. Как это можно исправить, или как это вообще лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.change-classes').on('change', function () { filterLessons(); });
$('.change-objects').on('change', function () { filterLessons(); });

function  filterLessons() {
  let vClass  = $('.change-classes option:selected').text();
  let vObject = $('.change-objects option:selected').text();
  $('.lessons-list .lessons-block').each(function() {
    $(this).css({ 
      display: ($(this).data('object') != vObject || $(this).data('class') != vClass)? 'none' : 'inherit' 
    });
  });
}
```